# HTML Python Correct Syntax

Tags: python, html, forms, syntax

I'm trying to print a textbox within a form.

This is my code for the component of the form (within python):

```
print "<tr><td>Review </td><td>< input type=""textarea"" name=""Review"" cols=""50"" rows=""5""> "
print """
    Enter some text...
    </textarea>
    <br />

"""
```

But on the form, it ends up like this [image]

I'm sure it's just syntax, but I'm pretty new to HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
print "<tr><td>Review </td><td><input type=\"textarea\" name=\"Review\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"5\" />"
print """
    Enter some text...
    </textarea>
    <br />

"""
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a redundant whitespace between `<` and `input`. Just remove it:

```
print "<tr><td>Review </td><td><input type=""textarea"" name=""Review"" cols=""50"" rows=""5""> "
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add `\` before each `"` symbol like this:

```
print "<tr>
     <td>Review </td>
     <td><input type=\"textarea\" name=\"Review\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"5\" />"
print """
    Enter some text...
    </textarea>
    </td>    
"""
```

And you must close `<td>` correctly (you typed `<br/>` instead).

Answer (score 0):

```
print "<tr><td>Review </td><td><textarea name=""Review"" cols=""50"" rows=""5"">Enter Some text"
print """
    </textarea>
    <br />

"""
```

This was actually the way I got it working... but yeah, the space after the < wasn't helping :P